# Кастомная страница в админке Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте.
Как создать кастомную страницу в админке Wordpress, и и чтобы она при обновлении Wordpress не удалилась?

На этой странице хочу выводить для заказчика подобие шпаргалки со ссылками на видео ютуб.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией `add_menu_page()` в файле `functions.php` шаблона

Делается это примерно так:

```
function add_help_menu() {
    add_menu_page(
        'Admin Help', // имя в меню
        'Admin Help Page', // title страницы
        'manage_options', // уровень доступа
        'admin_help', // slug страницы
        'render_help_page', // функция, отображающая собственно страницу
        'dashicons-editor-help', // иконка
        '10' // позиция в меню
    );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_help_menu');

function render_help_page() {
    echo '<p>hello world!</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Любая страница созданная в WP через админку после обновления останется.

Лучше всего подойдет плагин Custom Post Type Maker, он предоставит вам все обязательные типы постов, которых в большинстве случаев вам будет достаточно. В этом плагине есть два основных раздела: Post Types и Taxonomies.
Чтобы работать с Custom Post Type Maker, вам не понадобятся какие-то навыки программирования, здесь все доступно через удобный интерфейс.
Плагин покажет вам все другие типы пользовательских постов, которые вы уже зарегистрировали на сайте (даже те, которые не были созданы с помощью этого плагина).
В целом, очень удобный и практичный инструмент, который отлично справляется с поставленной перед ним задачей.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Вы меня не так поняли) Страница мне нужна не на сайте а в админке.