# Как добавить фильтр который будет работать только из адмники? WordPress

Tags: wordpress, hook

У меня есть вот такой фильтр.

```
add_filter('request', 'handle', 11, 1);
function handle( $array ) {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/wp-admin/my-custom-url') {
        echo 'Запрос сделан';  
    }
}
```

Он не работает, как мне сделать чтобы при попадании на /wp-admin/my-custom-url выводился текст(Запрос сделан)?

Подскажите может какой то хук использовать?

Comment: Тебе же не хук нужен, а создать свою страницу в админке? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526076/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B5-wordpress

Comment: А могу я на этой странице как то выводить голый JSON через wp_send_json?

Comment: Что в ней напишешь то и будет. По ссылке выше - это не единственный способ. И правильнее делать плагином, а не в теме.

Comment: Я понял спасибо большое за помощь.